# no resource found error in menu.xml

Tags: android, menu

this is my menu type android xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <group android:id="@+id/rose" android:menuCategory="container" android:visible="true">
        <item android:icon="@drawable/login.png"  android:id="@layout/activity_login_page"></item>
        <item android:id="@layout/activity_registration__page" android:icon="@drawable/registration.png"></item>
        <item android:id="@layout/activity_online_shopping" android:icon="@drawable/shopping.png"></item>
        <item android:id="@layout/activity_your_total_bill" android:icon="@drawable/logout.png"></item>
    </group>
</menu>
```

this is the error i found  but i have resource all in my drawable folder

```
 W/ResourceType( 3000): Bad XML block: header size 116 or total size 0 is larger than data size 0
[2012-11-22 15:32:20 - OrderPlacemnet] E:\workspace\OrderPlacemnet\res\menu\rosemenu.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/login.png').
[2012-11-22 15:32:20 - OrderPlacemnet] E:\workspace\OrderPlacemnet\res\menu\rosemenu.xml:5: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/registration.png').
[2012-11-22 15:32:20 - OrderPlacemnet] E:\workspace\OrderPlacemnet\res\menu\rosemenu.xml:6: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/shopping.png').
[2012-11-22 15:32:20 - OrderPlacemnet] E:\workspace\OrderPlacemnet\res\menu\rosemenu.xml:7: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/logout.png').
```

please help me for finding error

Comment: Doing a "clean project" in eclipse might solve your issue.

Comment: make sure you have place `logout.png` image in `res/drawable` folder and clean your project from Project->Clean... in Eclipse IDE

Comment: please reply me any answer as soon as possible

Comment: android 101 : don't put the `.png` part.

Comment: hey imran khan  i clean the project so it doesnt show me the R file...now what to do? entire R file crash...

Comment: but i want png means picture show there in options menu

Comment: once delete .png in item example android:icon="@drawable/registration"and check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the inclusion of `.png` in the `src` tag on the menu items.  You should not include it.  Your menu code should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <group android:id="@+id/rose" android:menuCategory="container" android:visible="true">
        <item android:icon="@drawable/login"  android:id="@layout/activity_login_page"></item>
        <item android:id="@layout/activity_registration_page" android:icon="@drawable/registration"></item>
        <item android:id="@layout/activity_online_shopping" android:icon="@drawable/shopping"></item>
        <item android:id="@layout/activity_your_total_bill" android:icon="@drawable/logout"></item>
    </group>
</menu>
```

Comment: but i want include image for item then what to do...because every png its generate the error

Comment: You are including the images.  Just omit the `.png` part from the menu definition.  Build process will pick it up automatically.

Answer (score 0):

please remove .png in your menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <group android:id="@+id/rose" android:menuCategory="container" android:visible="true">
        <item android:icon="@drawable/login"  android:id="@layout/activity_login_page"></item>
        <item android:id="@layout/activity_registration__page" android:icon="@drawable/registration"></item>
         <item android:id="@layout/activity_online_shopping" android:icon="@drawable/shopping"></item>
          <item android:id="@layout/activity_your_total_bill" android:icon="@drawable/logout"></item>
    </group>



</menu>
```